# 404 not found error when new form, controller is added

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I have created a new module with three forms, first two forms are working fine but when I created a third new form with controller, block and its xml file in layout.

It says 404 not found. I have done the same steps as for the previous two forms and they are working fine

also when I try to run di:compile command it is also not completely working it just stuck in this step

Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 44.0 MiB

Below is the code

> routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>     
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Module_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> test_order_print.xml

```
<head>
<title>Return with revocation</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <referenceContainer  name="content">
    <block class="Module\Test\Block\Order\Print" name="module_print" template="Module_Test::print.phtml" />     
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

> Controller

```
<?php

namespace Module\Test\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Print extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory= $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump('test print');
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> Block

```
<?php
namespace Module\Test\Block\Order;

class Print extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }        
}
```

> phtml file

```
<h1>test1</h1>
```

the url will be:

http://localhost/magento2/test/order/print -->not working

previous forms
http://localhost/magento2/test/order/index working
http://localhost/magento2/test/order/view working

View.php file in controller

```
<?php

namespace Module\Test\Controller\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

    class View extends Action
    {


        protected $pageFactory;
        protected $_coreSession;    
        public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession)
        {
            $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        /**
         * Execute action based on request and return result
         *
         * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
         *
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
         */
        public function execute()
        {
        $orderNumber = $this->_coreSession->getOrderNumber();
        $resultPage = $this->pageFactory->create();
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('returnOrderPrint')) {
            $this->_redirect('test/order/print');
        }
        return $resultPage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share View.php file code ?

Comment: for the controller or for the block?

Comment: @AmitBera, I have updated the question View.php file its the controller file

Comment: @AmitBera any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In

> test_order_print.xml

instead

```
<head>
<title>Return with revocation</title>
</head> 
<body>
    <referenceContainer  name="content">
    <block class="Module\Test\Block\Order\Print" name="module_print" template="Module_Test::print.phtml" />     
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

insert it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Module\Test\Block\Order\Print" before="-" template="Module_Test::print.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: @MyKhailo....it didn't work

Comment: There are no errors in the files you have downloaded. I checked myself and your code works well.

Comment: I have renamed files from Print to some different name of template, controller, block and it started to work again. Strange.